# Calendar show selected date

Tags: java, android, calendar

I know this is a repeated question but I'm still unable to solve this.

Example calendar showing current date: 21/2/19
user selected: 20/1/2019

problem:
calendar will show current date instead of user selected date.
much help appreciated.

**UPDATED**

[image]

i was able to get the selected date from datepicker dialog and display in textview. 
but right now i want the calendar to show the same date display in textview not showing current date.

Example: user selected date: 21/1/2019, Calendar should show date: 21/1/2019, not current date 22/2/2019
thanks :)

Comment: Your code isn't complete. Can you post the complete code?

Comment: Hi all, kindly refer to @Bhoomika Patel for the answer. I've tested and result was expected. Cheers :)

Comment: Hi all, kindly also refer to @user392117 for the answer. I've tested and result was expected as well. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare this globally:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
```

and

```
private void showDatePicker() {

   long timeInMillis = getmilifromdate(tvDate.getText().toString);
   c.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);

    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    //2018-08-15
                    selectedDate = year + "-" + ((monthOfYear + 1)) + "-" + (dayOfMonth);
    c.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                    tvDate.setText(selectedDate);
               }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

**EDIT**

get time milliseconds from time

```
public long getmilifromdate(String datei) // 2015-11-21
    {
        Date date = null;
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd);
            date = sdf.parse(datei);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date == null ? System.currentTimeMillis() : date.getTime();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, but this does not meet my requirement. i wanted the calendar to show selected date from textview example: textview date: 21/1/2019, calendar should show 21/1/2019 not 22/2/2019. much appreciated :)

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Hi @user392117 thanks a lot. Tested and result as expected. Cheers :)

Comment: glad that helps you. Mark the answer as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Calender is showing 0 to 11 Month. Use below function.

```
     private int mYear, mMonth, mDay;
     private String selectedDate;
     Calendar cal;
```

put this code in OnCreate of your activity

```
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    Date c = cal.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    selectedDate = df.format(c);

    mYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Now put this on click of your button

```
    private void showDatePicker() {

// This will show you previously selected date.      
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, mMonth);
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, mDay);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                    mMonth = monthOfYear;
                    mDay = dayOfMonth;
                    mYear = year;

                        //2018-08-15
                        selectedDate = year + "-" + ((monthOfYear + 1)) + "-" + (dayOfMonth);
                        tvDate.setText(selectedDate);
                   }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

      datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, but this does not meet my requirement. i wanted the calendar to show selected date from textview example: textview date: 21/1/2019, calendar should show 21/1/2019 not 22/2/2019. much appreciated

Comment: @Arduino check my updated answer, I have modified it. It will help you

Comment: Hi @Bhoomika Patel, thank you very much. I have tested and result was as expected. cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Calendar class is showing 0 to 11 Month in onDateSet callback.

Please consider following documenatation

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener

so you have to increment month with 1.

I think its now clear for you.